# How Can I Initialize My HostApduService from an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, nfc

I need to initialize my `HostApduService` with an `ApduResponse` object, the responses in `processCommandApdu` will be created using this `ApduResponse` object. I want to initialize my `HostApduService` after I get response from network to create my `ApduResponse` object. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing information to a HostApduService from another Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018121/passing-information-to-a-hostapduservice-from-another-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the doc, HCE service is launched when Reader with specific AID is tapped to your device(HCE).
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#HceServices

> One of the key advantages of a service is that it can run in the
>   background without any user interface. This is a natural fit for many
>   HCE applications like loyalty or transit cards, with which the user
>   shouldn't need to launch the app to use it. Instead, tapping the
>   device against the NFC reader starts the correct service (if not
>   already running) and executes the transaction in the background. Of
>   course, you are free to launch additional UI (such as user
>   notifications) from your service if that makes sense.

To send specific ApduResponse to your service, you need to communicate between your application and your HCE service. Please read this : [Passing information to a HostApduService from another Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018121/passing-information-to-a-hostapduservice-from-another-context)